# Post array of json objects to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring

I have problems with sending and receiving a list of json objects (jQuery Ajax)

Java Object

```
public class UserSkill () {

 private long user;
 private long skill;
 private long level;

 //getter and setter methods

}
```

From Controller i get list of objects and it looks like this

```
$.getJSON("getList", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

//console log ->  [Object { user=4, skill=61, leve=10}, Object { user=3, skill=61, level=20}]
```

I changed some values and we have following code

```
ioarray = [];

//update methods

console.log(ioarray);

//console log ->  [Object { user=4, skill=61, level=9000 }, Object { user=3, skill=61, level=100 }]
```

Ajax POST

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'goUpdate',
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: ioarray,
    succcess : function(e) {
        alert('Yeah');
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "goUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object goUpdatePOST(@RequestBody List<UserSkill> list) {

        //list.get(0).getLevel(); 

        return list;
}
```

Logs

```
type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

Something wrong here ... any ideas?

UPDATE;

Controler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "goUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String goUpdatePOST(@RequestBody UserSkill[] list) {

    for(UserSkill i : list) {
        System.out.println(i.getSkill());
    }
    return "somepage";

}
```

jQuery

```
var ioarray = [{ user:4, skill:61, level:10}, 
{ user:3,  skill:61, level:20}];

        $.ajax({
            url : 'goUpdate',
            type : 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(ioarray),
        });
```

Console output

```
JSON
0
    Object { user=4, skill=61, level=10}

1
    Object { user=3, skill=61, level=20}

Source
[{"user":4,"skill":61,"level":10},{"user":3,"skill":61,"level":20}]
```

to pom.xml inserted jackson-mapper-asl and jackson-core-asl.

Of course this example generate same error... What i am doing wrong? I think I checked every possibility.

Comment: try removing  `dataType : 'json'`

Comment: No... POST source: undefined=&undefined=

Comment: try removing `@RequestBody` then, there is some issue with the data posted and its type.

Comment: I did like that in data: {list: ioarray}, still occour like above but post at now: list%5B0%5D%5Buser%5D=4&list%5B0%5D%5Bskill%5D=61&list%5B0%5D%5Blevel%5D=10&list%5B1%5D%5Buser%5D=3&list%5B1%5D%5Bskill%5D=61&list%5B1%5D%5Blevel%5D=20

Comment: so now your data is getting enocded using UT-8 format, 
try removing `dataType : 'json'`

Comment: @ankur-singhal, i did what u wanted but it didn't help. Check my update if you can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this works for you

```
    $.ajax({
        url : 'goUpdate',
        type : 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(ioarray),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
```

Comment: it doesn't work too ... I think it probably is not a problem with JSON, but what else?

Comment: @user2363971 can you inspect using firebug what exactly is getting posted in data

Comment: Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Content-Length 97
Content-Type application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie JSESSIONID=BF78D2145022CEAC47AF35260444E8B2
Host localhost:8069
Referer http://localhost:8069/xxx/indexpage
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @user2363971 i am talking about the post request, the json that is being posted

Comment: I know it late but the problem was <csrf /> (spring security). Your solution was correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use value = "**/**goUpdate"

`@RequestMapping(value = "/goUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: have goUpdate path some prefix? or is running like localhost/goUpdate??

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem i didn't find any solution at last i have find another solution using simple `HttpServletRequest`.
You may use `HttpServletRequest` to read request data and use JSON API to convert this json String into `List<UserSkill>` object. You may use [GSON API](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for converting your json string into list .

For this you need following changed in controller class method as shown below :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "goUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String goUpdatePOST(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    String jsonStr = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type  fooType = new TypeToken<List<UserSkill>>() {}.getType();
    List<UserSkill> list = gson.fromJson(jsonStr,fooType);
    return gson.toJson(list);
}
```

In response send JSON string which can be created by converting `List<UserSkill>` into JSON string using Gson API.

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : 'json', 
        url : 'addAdmin',  
        data : JSON.stringify(ioarray)
 })
```

Controller (note it takes a custom String only). Then it uses Jackson to parse the string manually, because Spring won't do it in this case. (Spring will only auto-parse if you're using @ModelAttribute form binding.)

```
@PostMapping("/addAdmin")
public boolean addAdmin(@RequestBody String json) throws Exception {

      String decodedJson = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(json, "UTF-8");
      ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // This is Jackson
      List<UserRolesGUIBean> userRolesGUIBeans =  jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(
              decodedJson, new TypeReference<List<UserRolesGUIBean>>(){});
      // Now I have my list of beans populated.
}
```